# Undefined route brings list of avalaible routes in production env

Tags: production, vaadin14

I realized my first WebApp with Vaadin 14 and deployed it to Tomcat 9 on the production server.

So far everything is working great, but when I'm using a non-existing route in the client browser the system responds with a plain text list of all available routes and shows even the following line on the bottom:

> "This detailed message is only shown when running in development mode."

I have created the WAR-file with "-pProduction" and the startup-log of Tomcat does not show any dev-mode-message.

Any ideas what happens here? Thanks for reading my first question on this platform!

I worked my way through the Vaadin docs and tried the following entry in application.properties:

```
vaadin.productionMode=true
```

But nothing changed?

Answer (score 1):

This is a known vulnetability CVE-2021-31413 in Vaadin 14.6.1 and older versions. The resolution is to update the Vaadin version to 14.6.2. The latest version is 14.9.1 as of writing this. Naturally I recommend that.

https://vaadin.com/security/cve-2021-31412

Comment: Thanks for your support! I am already using Vaadin 14.7. but you set me on the right track with the given link.
I will implement an error handler and upgrade to 14.9.1
Thanks again!